# Split single row into multiple rows based on week of the month in date

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, common-table-expression

I have a table like this

```
Id      Valid_From    Valid_To
9744    24/06/2019    07/07/2019
9745    12/08/2019    31/12/9999
```

I would like to split this table into multiple rows based on the week like this by joining to the date table

```
Id      Valid_from   Valid_To    Month       Week
9744    24/06/2019   07/07/2019  June        4
9744    24/06/2019   07/07/2019  July        1
9744    24/06/2019   07/07/2019  July        2
9745    12/08/2019   31/12/9999  August      2
9745    12/08/2019   31/12/9999  August      3
9745    12/08/2019   31/12/9999  August      4
```

In this case there will be 3 rows as the valid from and valid two falls between these 3 weeks for ID - 9744

For ID - 9745 the Valid_to date is infinity so we need to just take all the week in the current month from the valid_from date

I then just need to append the output with Month and the Week number

Can someone help me to write a query to have this output?

Thanks

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using.  How do you define `week`?  What is the "date" table"?

Answer (score 0):

You mention a "date" table.  If you have one then you can use a `join` like this:

```
select distinct t.id, valid_from, t.valid_to, d.month, d.week
from yourtable t join
     date d
     on d.date >= t.valid_from and
        d.date <= t.valid_to;
```

Comment: Yes there is a Date table.                                                                                 
  Shouldn't there be any where clause?  For ex - where d.day_start_date IN 
  ('2019-01-07 00:00:00.000', '2019-01-14 00:00:00.000', '2019-01-21 00:00:00.000', '2019-01-28 00:00:00.000', '2019-01-29 00:00:00.000') This lists all the week start date from the date table for the month of Jan for instance?

Comment: If we don't put a where clause then i believe it will produce match for every date (1st,2nd,3rd..) instead of just 7th, 14th, 21th, 28th i believe or am i wrong?

Comment: @Vijai . . . The `on` clause handles the ranges.  The `select distinct` removes duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right, you need to list all month names and week numbers of these months' existing between `valid_from` and `valid_to` dates. I did it by following query:

```
SELECT 
  Q.ID, 
  Q.VALID_FROM,
  Q.VALID_TO,
  Q.MONTH_NAME,
  WEEK_NUMBER
FROM
(
  SELECT
    CEIL((Q.DATES_BETWEEN_INTERVAL - FIRST_DAY_OF_MONTH + 1) / 7) WEEK_NUMBER,
    TO_CHAR(Q.DATES_BETWEEN_INTERVAL, 'MONTH', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American') MONTH_NAME,
    Q.* 
  FROM
  (
    SELECT  
      LEVEL + S.VALID_FROM DATES_BETWEEN_INTERVAL,
      TRUNC(LEVEL + S.VALID_FROM, 'MONTH') FIRST_DAY_OF_MONTH,
      S.* FROM
    (
      SELECT T.*, 
        (CASE WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM T.VALID_TO) = 9999 THEN LAST_DAY(T.VALID_FROM) ELSE T.VALID_TO END) - T.VALID_FROM DAYS_COUNT
      FROM AAA_TABLE T
    ) S
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= S.DAYS_COUNT
  ) Q
) Q
GROUP BY 
  Q.ID, 
  Q.VALID_FROM,
  Q.VALID_TO,
  Q.MONTH_NAME,
  WEEK_NUMBER
ORDER BY
  Q.ID, 
  Q.VALID_FROM,
  Q.VALID_TO,
  Q.MONTH_NAME,
  WEEK_NUMBER;
```

But there must be **5th** week if the date greater than **28th** day of month. Hope this will help you.

Comment: Hi, thanks but just want to know if using a date table will help reducing the query complexity?

Comment: How do you decide to create date table?

Comment: There is a Calendar Date table which we refer to date column, it has day_start_date, month, week, year ...Just wondering joining this Date table and pulling just the Month and week from there and joining with Base table(AAA_TABLE) can be done?

Comment: Yes, in my opinion this will meet your requirement. I did not know that your calerdar dates table exists in your db. I thought that you have one table (in this case AAA_TABLE) and you need to write one query to show results as you show in the example. That is why I created this query

Comment: Yes, sorry there is a Date table we can use for pulling the month and week, can you please show me incorporating this Date table and modifying your query?

Comment: Can you put your `Date` table structure in your question? Please let me know `Date` table description(which columns do it have)